# How can I store and use a value anywhere in python?

Tags: python

I am trying to allow the user create a username through taking he information from an entry box. How can I store this value and use it anywhere in the code?

```
#user chooses username and moves to next frame
def signIn(self,page_name):
    #if textbox isn't empty
    if ebox.index("end") != 0:
        self.show_frame(page_name)
        ebox.destroy()
        global username
        username = ebox.get()
    else:
        app.mbox("Error", "Please enter a username", 1)
```

This of course doesn't work, but this is what I'm working from which of course can entirely be deleted.

Comment: Is the code part of a module?

Answer (score 0):

If you need to make `username` global, you'll need to first define it in the beginning of your file:

```
 username = str()
 # your code goes here...
```

Then you'll be able to do:

```
global username
```

and refer to it globally.